# Returning multiple values from a method based on a condition

Tags: java, conditional-statements, return-value

I have a function and I need to change the return value based on a condition, I managed to get only one return cause the data is static while I need to make it dynamic as shown in below code

```
public boolean outBound(int c_x, int c_y) {

    return (blackCarX > 150 && blackCarX < 690 && blackCarY > 200 && blackCarY < 500);

}
```

I need to say if the x or y equals a specific number, return a different output

any advice?

This is the error I am receiving for my condition:

`if (c_x > 150 && c_x < 690 && c_y > 200 && c_y < 500){ 
   return(c_x, x_y);
}`

> DrawCars.java:132: error: ')' expected return(c_x, x_y) ^
>   DrawCars.java:132: error: not a statement return(c_x, x_y) ^
>   DrawCars.java:132: error: ';' expected return(c_x, x_y)

Comment: Why not use `c_x` and `c_y` in your *condition*? Also what do you mean by *return a different output*?

Comment: No luck with `if-else` statements? :)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava when i use if statements, i get an error and its something wrong in the syntax but can't figure it out

Comment: Would love to see the error in your question.

Comment: @NicholasK cause as i mentioned i need to change it to be dynamic so i can use c_x instead of blackcarX for example

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava this is the condition 
 if (c_x > 150 && c_x < 690 && c_y > 200 && c_y < 500){
         return(c_x, x_y);}

error

DrawCars.java:132: error: ')' expected
         return(c_x, x_y)
                   ^
DrawCars.java:132: error: not a statement
         return(c_x, x_y)
                     ^
DrawCars.java:132: error: ';' expected
         return(c_x, x_y)

Comment: There you have it: `return(c_x, x_y);` is not a correct format for `return`. Lookup the correct way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if else statement

```
public boolean outBound(int c_x, int c_y) {
  if(blackCarX > 150){
      return a;
  } else if (blackCarX < 690){
    return b; 
  }
}
```

if you have only 2 values you can also use ? statement

```
public boolean outBound(int c_x, int c_y) {

  return blackCarX > 150 ?  a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an if-else statement

or,

the ?: operator

Your question is not clear on how you want to use c_x or c_y so I'm making my own little example below.

For instance,

1. if-else statement

   `if(a > b) {
       return i;
   } else {
       return j;`
2. ?: operator

`(a > b) ? return i : return j` // This does same thing as 1.